# Node.js - Package Database Calls With NPM or In Module

Tags: database, node.js, encapsulation, npm

I was recently interviewed by a technical architect and he mentioned that his group has begun to consolidate all domain-based database calls into packages. He said this had significant advantages when sharing code and devising TDD (should.js). Is this a recommended practice? What are the advantages/disadvantages of using packages for encapsulating such resource IO? Please include links, if available. Thanks.

Comment: Hello Chris, your question is a little vague and it's hard to guess what exactly you are asking. You can edit it and try to ask for something more specific. For example: "Can I encapsulate IO logic inside modules?" If that's what you are asking.

Comment: This is just what I said. I tried to clarify his statement by asking if they are using module.exports to encapsulate logic and he said they are using NPM to generate packages and share code across departments as node modules. Hey this is what I heard? Does this make sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use npm packages to share code between projects since that's what packages do. Starting out with a package is probably a bad idea. You mostly start with a module and if needed extract out a package.

Comment: So maybe their experience has matured to the point where they extracted specific functionality and decided to package it for other department IT projects. Thanks.